# How to get dark menu bar and dock in Mojave light mode?

Tags: macos, mojave

I prefer light windows with dark menu bar as in High Sierra. However, it seems I can only choose all-dark or all-light in Mojave now. Are there any way to hybrid or customize it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

`defaults write -g NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool Yes`

Then logout or restart. Then go to the system preferences and select dark mode. It will make top bar and dock dark while everything else in light mode.

To revert it back:

```
defaults write -g NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool No
```

EDIT: **Please also have a look on the answers bellow, they are needed in order to make other parts working, like notification center & spotlight. Run all of the commands, and then logout.** Still missing the trash can color :)

Comment: Thanks! It works, but my spotlight is still in light mode and my trash bin is dark lol

Comment: If anyone knows a way to make only the menu bar dark (and not the dock), please post the solution

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks the sidebar colours and makes part of it unreadable

Comment: To revert it back by deleting the setting instead of overwriting: `defaults delete -g NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance`

Comment: Be careful with this solution as it may break certain apps, for example I found that all Firefox windows were solid black, and the Zoom.us app could not join meetings. The setting had to be deleted, not set to "No".

Comment: @ChrisLundie above: I can still join Zoom.us meetings and Firefox respects my theme (but I have custom colors installed). My main issue is that the volume up/down overlay has unreadable (black on black) volume blocks.

Answer (score 7):

Apologies for making a separate answer but I didn't have enough reputation to comment.

The accepted answer works for getting the menu bar and dock to be dark but leaves the Notification Center sidebar really difficult to see. In order to make Notification Center readable again, do:

```
defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool No
```

Comment: I am using 'reduce transparency', some text of today widget is not readable anyway (img attached). Is there any method to use a light notification center like in 10.13? https://imgur.com/a/XwaDATz

Comment: Is there any way to make the trash bin not black..?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

`defaults write com.apple.Spotlight NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool No`

PS: Remember reboot or logout