# How to change macOS Mojave’s menu bar transparency

Tags: mojave, system-settings

How do you change the menu bar transparency in MacOS Mojave?

Comment: would system pref -> accessibility-> display work? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337478/how-to-get-dark-menu-bar-and-dock-in-mojave-light-mode?rq=1

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, it's best practice to outline what you've already tried, otherwise you're likely to get suggestions for things you've already done. Plus it gives us more context around your problem.