# How to get permanent dark menu bar & dock, but still use light & dark mode?

Tags: macos, dock, menu-bar, dark-mode

I know how to get a [dark menu bar and dock in light mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337478/how-to-get-dark-menu-bar-and-dock-in-mojave-light-mode), but that option disables the use of the full dark mode on macOS completely. I'm wondering if it's possible at all to still use light and dark mode, while having the menu bar and dock permanently dark.

(Years of using the dark menu bar and dock have really made me dislike the look and distraction of the light versions.)